Insert array from html dynamic table to mysql using javascript and php
I have a dynamic table in html & javascript. I want to insert the table rows into the mysql database. here is my code:
var table1 = document.getElementById("mytable");
var hid1, hid2, hid3, hid4, hid5, hid6, hid7, hid8;

for (var r = 1, n = table1.rows.length; r < n; r++){
    var c1 = table1.rows[r].cells[1].innerHTML;
    var c2 = table1.rows[r].cells[2].innerHTML;
    var c3 = table1.rows[r].cells[3].innerHTML;
    var c4 = table1.rows[r].cells[4].innerHTML;
    var c5 = table1.rows[r].cells[5].innerHTML;
    var c6 = table1.rows[r].cells[6].innerHTML;
    var c7 = table1.rows[r].cells[7].innerHTML;
    var c8 = table1.rows[r].cells[8].innerHTML;
             
    hid1 = c1;
    hid2 = c2;
    hid3 = c3;
    hid4 = c4;
    hid5 = c5;
    hid6 = c6;
    hid7 = c7;
    hid8 = c8;         
}


$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "shipment-action.php",
  data: {
     'checking_form2':true,
      'transactioncode': transactioncode,
      'ordercode': hid1,
      'productname': hid2,
      'qty': hid3,
      'unit': hid4,
      'weight': hid5,
      'price': hid6,
       'discount': hid7,
       'amount': hid8,
   },
   success: function (response) {
       alert(response)
   }
});

if(isset($_POST['checking_form2'])){

    $transactioncode = $_POST['transactioncode'];
    $ordercode = $_POST['ordercode'] ;
    $productname = $_POST['productname'];
    $qty= $_POST['qty'];
    $unit= $_POST['unit'];
    $weight= $_POST['weight'];
    $price= $_POST['price'];
    $amount= $_POST['amount'];
    $discount= $_POST['discount'];

    $count = count($_POST['ordercode']);

    //Current Date
    $current_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    
    $amount_format = str_replace(".", "", $amount);
    $discount_format = str_replace(".", "", $discount);
    $weight_format = str_replace(".", "", $weight);
    

    for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
        $sql = $conn->query("INSERT INTO shipment_product VALUES ('','','$transactioncode','$ordercode','','$productname','$qty','$unit','$weight','$price','$discount','','ON_PROCESS')");
    }

    

    if($sql){
        echo $response = "Succesfully";
        
    } else {
        echo $response = "Ouch, No";
    }
}

I get an error like this:

count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in

if I only insert one row in the table and don't use looping, this can work fine. the problem is when i use lopping to insert multiple rows i get this problem. can you help me to find and understand this problem?

To which line is the error referring?

$count = count($_POST['ordercode']);

you're not sending arrays. Each time through the for loop you overwrite all the variables with the values from the current row. At the end they just contain the values from the last row.

You should declare all the hidX varibles as arrays, and use hidX.push(cX) to get arrays of all the values.

It's 2024. Learn to use let rather than var for your variable declarations.

The error indicates, that your $_POST['ordercode'] variable is not an array. This variable is set in your ajax call to the value of hid1. Like mentioned before, the loop doesn't make sense here, as you're overwriting these variables every time and you end with a single value per hidX variable, not an array.
